# How do I select lightning radio input in such a way that it deselects the other radiobuttons automatically?

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, html

Need help with fixing radiobuttion selection. In the image, you can see all buttons selected but only one button should be selected and others should be deselected automatically.  with Standard HTML Input type radio, it works fine. But I want to try with Lightning Input radio button

**Component Page**
[image]

**HTML CODE**
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify a `name` and `value`, just as you would in [normal HTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio).

```
<lightning-input name={item.id} type="radio" value={item.options.a}></lightning-input>
```

This will allow you to get the radio behavior, as well as tell which item is selected.

Note that the `name` must be the same for all `type="radio"` that should behave as a single radio selection, which is why I used item.id as the unique name. You can derive another name if you desire, just make sure they are unique on the page.

[Demo](https://webcomponents.dev/edit/u5viKTaLbFXKCackPdb7/src/app.css?p=stories).

Comment: OMG @sfdcfox It worked!!!! Thanks so much. you are a pure genius. God bless you.